# Node application doesn't run after deploying to Azure using Github Actions (my node app stored in subfolder of github repo)

Tags: node.js, azure, express, deployment, github-actions

My node.js (express) server doesn't start after deployment to Azure.

I've got several project in one github repo. Here is the structure:

```
.github
  workflows
    main_serverexamplewebapp.yml
src
  server_example
    package.json
    server.js
  project_2
```

I want to deploy src/server_example to Azure Web App and run server.js.

main_serverexamplewebapp.yml

```yaml
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - serverexamplewebapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        working-directory: ./src/server_example
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'serverexamplewebapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_12345 }}
          package: .
```

server.js

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();



// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome!" });
});



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "server_example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

Github Actions finished successfully (both build and deploy). There are no errors In Azure Deployment Center too:

```
Deployment successful. deployer = GITHUB_ZIP_DEPLOY deploymentPath = ZipDeploy. Extract zip.
```

But when I open url there is default azure message "Your web app is running and waiting for your content".

What should I do to run my server.js on Azure after deployment?

Comment: Can you provide your github repository link if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did these things to fix the problem:

1. **Changed `main_serverexamplewebapp.yml`:** I've changed `path` in `actions/upload-artifact@v2` from `.` to `./src/server_example` (it's path to my project inside my repo). Here is the the correct fragment:

   ```
   - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
     uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
     with:
         name: node-app
         path: ./src/server_example
   ```
2. **Added `npm run start` to Azure Configuration** ("Configuration" in left column -> "General settings" tab -> add `npm run start` to "Startup command" input)
   [image: Azure Configuration]